# Non-upgrade websocket connection on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket

So I'm using websockets, and for a client behind a content filtering proxy (blue coat) it strips the upgrade headers for websockets so that they just look like normal HTTP requests.

Headers:

```
{ host: 'example.com',
origin: 'http://example.info',
pragma: 'no-cache',
'cache-control': 'no-cache',
'sec-websocket-key': 'NIeTzdQwd3TYambNSzR6lg==',
'sec-websocket-version': '13',
'sec-websocket-extensions': 'x-webkit-deflate-frame',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36',
connection: 'Keep-Alive',
'x-bluecoat-via': 'b6e771e9e7ed72d2' }
```

To solve this problem, I need to either a) somehow fake the websocket well enough for [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws) to be able to handle it... or b) figure out how to proxy something to connect to a different port, and forward that connection onto Heroku. I'm interested in the lowest-touch solution possible, because this is for a one-off client.

Does anyone know how to do any of the above? Option c) is to rewrite the api using sock.js or something like that, which is where I'm going to head if this last ditch effort doesn't work.